# jquery, multiply selectors and OR function

Tags: jquery, function, animation, click, jquery-animate

Hi guys I have this code:

```
$('#riscButton, #eneButton, #giardButton').one("click", function(){
                $('.content').animate(
                    {"height":"+=620px"},
                    500,
                    'easeOutBounce');
                $('#eneButton').animate(
                    { "top":"+=310px"},
                    1500,
                    'easeInOutExpo');
                $('#eneButton').animate(
                    {"left":"-=310px"},
                    1500,
                    'easeOutBounce')
                $('#giardButton').animate(
                    {"top":"+=620px"},
                    2000,
                    'easeInOutExpo')
                });
```

As you can see if someone click on a button an animation has to happend, not important which button you click you have the same animation. with the one() I say to the button that has to be clicked one time only and here is the matter, how can i say to the script that if you press one button even the others must be disabled after?
right now for example if I click the first button the animation happend and ok, if I reclick the same button nothing happend, but if I click on the second or third button the animation starts again. how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to unbind the event from *all* the elements, not just the one you clicked:

```
$('#a, #b, #c').click(function() {
    alert('clicked');

    $('#a, #b, #c').off('click');
});​
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/peFff/3/**

---

A better solution would be to use classes:

```
$('.clickable').click(function() {
    alert('clicked');

    $('.clickable').off('click');
});​
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/peFff/5/**

Comment: I would do it this way, but also use a class on each of the buttons, rather than referring to them by each of their IDs separately.

Comment: just give each button desired a class, example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peFff/4/)

Comment: @TomPietrosanti: I edited that into my answer *right* as you commented.

Comment: Must be we have great minds, because I hear they think alike :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the selector.
For example: `$('#riscButton, #eneButton, #giardButton').attr('disabled','disabled')` in your function. that selector returns you an array with all the buttons...
And then you should unbind the buttons... by doing `$('#riscButton, #eneButton, #giardButton').off('click.button')`

Add .button to your event name to [namespace](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) it and make it easier to find (it will also avoid unbinding undesired event handlers).

Last note: Last if you have to do things like `$('#a,#b,#c')` as a selector you should consider using a class instead (just makes the code much nicer)

Answer (score 0):

At first click, you could simply add a class to your container tag saying one button has been clicked. On subsequent clicks, check if container has the class before calling animations.